# I have issues starting the server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am new to the ruby environment. I configured ruby and when I start the server I am hit with the series of errors. Can someone please give me a hand please.

```
2.3.1 :001 > rails s 

NameError: undefined local variable or method `s' for main:Object
    from (irb):1
    from /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
    from /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
    from /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
    from /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/User/workspace/dineconnect-backend/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
    from /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/commands/rails.rb:6:in `call'
    from /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/command_wrapper.rb:38:in `call'
    from /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/application.rb:191:in `block in serve'
    from /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/application.rb:161:in `fork'
    from /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/application.rb:161:in `serve'
    from /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/application.rb:131:in `block in run'
    from /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `loop'
    from /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `run'
    from /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/User/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/User/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to start rails server in interactive Ruby Shell (IRB or irb), or may be rails console.

use the command

> rails s

in your terminal

You should have to look into this http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html for the rails basics.

Answer (score 0):

You are using rails console. Get out of the console by typing quit and then type `rails s`